# adding or converting between cv::Point3d and cv::Vec3d

Tags: c++, opencv

Since they both have three elements, it seems logical to have a overloaded addition operator to add between the two types. Or would this not make sense from a design point of view?

But since that doesn't exist, we have to convert `Vec3d` to `Point3d` first. [This link](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d6/dcf/classcv_1_1Vec.html) mentions there's a way to convert them but I don't see it. The best I could do is something like this:

```
void vecToPoint(const cv::Vec3d & v)
{
    cv::Point3d p;
    p.x = v[0];
    p.y = v[1];
    p.z = v[2];
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cv::Point3_<T>` has a [constructor](https://docs.opencv.org/4.0.0/df/d6c/classcv_1_1Point3__.html#a4ce6bcc3138662a2b4abb589120b25fb) which takes a generic `cv::Vec<T, 3>`. Note that `Point3d` and `Vec3d` are just typedefs with `T = double`. So it should be possible to simply do

```cpp
cv::Point3d p{v};  // or p(v) or p = v; you get it.
// ...
```